# NoMethodError in UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, nomethoderror

I'm getting stuck on an error I'm getting when signing up a new user in Michael Hart's Ruby on Rails Tutorial.  I'm new to rails but I've been searching for hours and can't seem to find anything to figure out the issue.  My initial thought is that it's specific to the following line:

```
redirect_to @user
```

This is my file for **users_controller.rb**

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

class UsersController < ApplicationController

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    ￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼    redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
end
```

This is the error message I get:

> NoMethodError in UsersController#create
>
> undefined method `￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼' for # Rails.root: /Users/mikedeverna/Documents/rails_projects/sample_app
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:18:in `create'

Here is the code in my `routes.rb` file:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy] 
root to: 'static_pages#home'
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

I am not able to find which is the right path . 
Cheers

Comment: Please check the resources :users path via `rake routes` .This will help you understand that which routes are available for you in which type of method .Keep in mind that create method will be post method for you

Comment: Why do you have the following lines in the users controller?  #!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something weird got pasted into your code. You're right about which line is causing the problem but it's not the redirect statement. It's this weird string right in front of it:

```
￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your ***app/models/user.rb***.

It may sound unexpected, but if you have an error in your model (e.g. validation of object method), then it will be unsuccessful in creating the object with proper properties, and result in a no method error when running the code:
`if @foo.save`

***side note** - This topic probably should be closed soon since this pertains to Rails 3.2 and may be less relevant in Rails 4.  I'm too new to Rails 4 to have a well-informed opinion on that.*